# MySQL Trigger only running one IF Query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger that runs on when a row is updated on the leads table:

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status_id <=> OLD.status_id THEN
        BEGIN
            insert into lead_status
                (lead_id, status_ID)
            values (OLD.id, NEW.status_id);
        END;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.user_id <=> OLD.user_id THEN
        BEGIN
            insert into lead_owner
                (lead_id, staff_ID)
            values (OLD.id, NEW.user_id);
        END;
    END IF;
END
```

However, it appears the only one that runs is the IF regarding the user_id. If I make a change with the status_id, the trigger does not appear to run.

Am I doing something wrong here for it not to run? I'm not getting any syntax errors when I save the trigger.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have simulate the same trigger as yours and it is work as expected. Below is the trigger code

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON order_data
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status_id <> OLD.status_id THEN
        BEGIN
            insert into lead_status
                (lead_id, status_ID)
            values (OLD.id, NEW.status_id);
        END;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.user_id <> OLD.user_id THEN
        BEGIN
            insert into lead_owner
                (lead_id, staff_ID)
            values (OLD.id, NEW.user_id);
        END;
    END IF;
END;
```

Assume the main table call order_data, i have change the status_id from "IN_PROGRESS" to "IN" for id "01". This is the order_data table result.
[image]

This is the lead_status table result. 
[image] 
Please retry by delete your current trigger and create using the code above. HTH.

Comment: The difference being that the OP has coded a null safe equal when a not equal is required?

Comment: @P.Salmon that was it, changing it to <> makes it work.